# Selectpicker does not refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have two dropdowns and trying to change second dropdown's elements according to first dropdown selection. Here is my html:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListIl" CssClass="selectpicker" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

<select id="DropDownListIlce" class="selectpicker" name="nameIlceler" runat="server"></select>
```

Don't think about how I populate first dropwdown, I am doing it in codebehind wihthout a problem. Now, my js(Jquery):

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
$("#<%=DropDownListIl.ClientID%>").change(function () {

        var id = $("#<%=DropDownListIl.ClientID%>").val();

        $("#<%=DropDownListIlce.ClientID%>").empty();

        for (i in ilceler) {
            if (ilceler[i].Ilid == id) {

                $("#<%=DropDownListIlce.ClientID%>").append("<option value='" + ilceler[i].Id + "'>" + ilceler[i].İlceAdi + "</option>");
            }
        }

        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

    });
```

`ilceler` is my object list which contains second dropdown's elements. The thing is, when I remove `selectpicker` class from my second dropdown, code just working fine. I change first dropwdown's selected item and second dropdown's element changes correctly but when I add `selectpicker` class to second dropdown, it's elements does not change. So I am pretty sure I just have problem with refreshing the second dropwdown. Like you see, I used `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');` but it seems like not working.

Comment: Wouldn't `$("#DropDownListIlce").selectpicker("refresh")` work ?
As you would be sure to refresh only the second picker

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I already tried it and it is not working. @GrégoireFruleux